# What do you call the original repo from which a fork is made?

Tags: git, github, terminology

What do you call the original repo from which a fork is made?

I know the "origin" is a shorthand name for the remote repository that a project was originally *cloned* from.

Is the repo from which a fork is made also called the origin?

Comment: You can only have one remote named origin, the convention is to call the repo you forked from "upstream": https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork

Comment: @jonrsharpe So if I were to suggest someone "please make a pull request to the upstream", would that make sense?

Comment: Yes. See https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to GitHub glossary, it is simply called the "original repository"

> ### Fork
>
> A fork is a personal copy of another user's repository that lives on your account. > Forks allow you to freely make changes to a project without affecting the original. Forks remain attached to the original, allowing you to submit a pull request to the original's author to update with your changes. You can also keep your fork up to date by pulling in updates from the original.

Source: https://help.github.com/en/articles/github-glossary#fork

### Edit (28/10/2021)

As mentioned by @ADTC's comment, the original repository is now called "upstream repository" :

> ### Upstream
>
> When talking about a branch or a fork, the primary branch on the original repository is often referred to as the "upstream", since that is the main place that other changes will come in from. The branch/fork you are working on is then called the "downstream". Also called origin.

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/github-glossary#upstream

Comment: They have updated the glossary, and now it's officially called the "upstream repository". It will be nice if you update your answer with the revised text.