# Unable to trigger GitHub Actions when pull request comes from a forked repository

Tags: github, github-actions

There is a private repository with a GitHub Actions workflow. When I create a pull request between branches in this repository, the GitHub Actions workflow is triggered correctly.

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - pre-production
      - production

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2
...
```

However, when another developer who only has read permission forks this repository, makes some commits, and then creates a pull request to the [Upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54802827/what-do-you-call-the-original-repo-from-which-a-fork-is-made), the GitHub Actions workflow is not triggered. I have confirmed that they created the pull request to the correct branch.

Is there a setting that allows other developers with read permission to trigger the GitHub Actions workflow in the [Upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54802827/what-do-you-call-the-original-repo-from-which-a-fork-is-made)?

---

**Updated:**

There is an option in the repository settings called "[Run workflows from fork pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#enabling-workflows-for-forks-of-private-repositories)", but I cannot enable it.

Comment: which branch developer pull request merge to ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan pre-production branch. I have confirmed that he pull request to the correct branch.

Comment: For public repositories, a maintainer needs to click some button to allow actions to be run in PRs from forks. Not sure if that's the case for this scenario as well.

Comment: @rethab would you mind telling me where is the button then I can check?

Comment: @Ying-ShanLin it is documented here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/approving-workflow-runs-from-public-forks

Comment: @rethab Thank you. There is no button like that.

Comment: If someone else arrives here: make sure your trigger is `pull_request`. Mine was `push` which also triggers for my own PRs (since I push to a branch that's mine) but it didn't trigger for forks which fruitlessly led me down this path.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally, I found a setting called "[Run workflows from fork pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#enabling-workflows-for-forks-of-private-repositories)". Enable it will solve the problem.

If the repository is under an organization, we should enable it in the organization settings. After that, we can enable it in the repository settings.

Comment: The 'Run workflows from fork pull requests' checkbox is disabled for me. What could be the reason?

Comment: @AnshulTiwari go to actions tab and enable it from there

Comment: @wc203 `Settings-> Actions-> General-> Fork pull request workflows-> Run workflows from fork pull requests` this is the path which is showing checkbox disabled to me.

Comment: @AnshulTiwari Is the repo under an organization?

Comment: @Ying-ShanLin Resolved now. Since the repository is managed by the organization, tweaking settings at the organizational level allowed me to adjust the flag as needed. 
Appreciate the support.